# PHP - Check if all entries in a table has the value 1 and then echo something

Tags: php, mysql

im currently stuck with an issue. Ive built a basic "team-work platform" in which you can set tasks in a to-do list. I've implemented the functionality that can mark a task as complete by setting the value of done to 1

I need to be able to check if all of the tasks in the list are set to done, and if so echo something. My code checks for the value 1, but it settles with a single entry being set to 1. But i need it to check if all tasks have the value 1 and if they do it should echo something.

```
$res3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE tasks.planet_id=1 AND        team_id=$teamid AND done=1") 
or die(mysql_error()); 
if ($res3 && mysql_num_rows($res3) > 0)
{
    echo 'Complete!'; 
}
else
{
echo 'Not done yet!';
}
```

I'll try to give you an example of how i want it to work: Lets say i have 10 tasks in the table. I want the code to recognise when all 10 of these tasks are marked as done with the value 1 set. And then echo "all your tasks are complete". So it needs to somehow loop through all the entries in the table and check if they are all set to 1, and when they are all set to 1 it echoes something.

Please help! :)

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  The code sample and the question don't really align.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `done` is an integer can can be either 0 or 1, you could do something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) total, SUM(done) totalDone FROM tasks WHERE tasks.planet_id=1 AND team_id=$teamid;
```

And then test in your PHP code that total == totalDone.

Alternatively, if you *really* want to only get a row out of the database when `total == totalDone` (as your comments seem to suggest), you could write something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) total, SUM(done) totalDone FROM tasks WHERE tasks.planet_id=1 AND team_id=$teamid) _X WHERE _X.total = _X.totalDone;
```

But that just adds a lot of extra complexity for no real gain, and I wouldn't recommend doing it that way.

Note that you [should not use mysql_* functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12860046/5760706) in new code, and should instead use either [mysqli](http://www.php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php). mysql_* is not recommended for new code.

Also, you should be careful with using variables directly in query strings. That can easily lead to sql injection vulnerabilities. [Instead, use parameterized queries with mysqli or PDO.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/5760706)

Comment: Hello and thank you! I tried your code and it gave me the same result. If you read what i replied to the above answer. The query executes when a single one of the tasks have done set to 1. I want it to ONLY execute when all of the tasks have "done" set to 1.

Comment: What code did you actually write, though? You need to get out of the MySQL the total number of tasks and the number that are done. Which means you need to actually retrieve the row and look at its values; you can't just look at the number of rows.

Comment: Perfect! This worked. The thing is, this is a school project for a company and it is only going to be run locally, therefor sql injection is not very likely. Also, the reason for this function is that when all tasks are completed you are to be "sent to the next planet" where you have to complete another set of tasks, and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to 'all tasks done' is best done with the question of how many tasks where done <> 1.

I.e.

```
SELECT count(*) as 'incomplete'
FROM tasks 
WHERE tasks.planet_id=1
  AND team_id=$teamid and done <> 1;
```

Therefore you're able to use the code:

```
if($res3) {
  $incompleteQueryResult = mysql_fetch_assoc($res3);
  if ($incompleteQueryResult['incomplete'] > 0) {
     echo "Not done yet";
  } else {
     echo "Complete!";
  }
} else {
  echo "Could not retrieve completed tasks";
}
```

If you still need to retrieve both the number of completed tasks as well as the number of incomplete, you could modify the query similar to the following.

```
SELECT 
  IF(done = 1, 'complete', 'incomplete') as status,
  COUNT(*) AS 'number_in_status'
FROM tasks 
WHERE tasks.planet_id=1
  AND team_id=$teamid
GROUP BY done
```

And you'll need to modify how you retrieve it in the PHP as well if so.

If you need to know all of the above, then either execute two queries (one as an aggregate/summary and one as the full data set) or keep track of it in a variable.  e.g.

```
$numIncompleteTasks = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res3)) {
  $numIncompleteTasks += ! (bool) $row['done']; 
}
// you now know how many tasks are incomplete.
```

You could modify this code to track both complete and incomplete.

### Deprecation notice.

I'd recommend reviewing your use of mysql_* functions - PHP deprecated and removed these functions in [recent versions of PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php).

Comment: Hello, and thanks for your contribution. Unfortunatly i get the same results as before. I'll try to give you an example of how i want it to work: Lets say i have 10 tasks in the table. I want the code to recognise when all 10 of these tasks are marked as done with the value 1 set. And then echo "all your tasks are complete". So it needs to somehow loop through all the entries in the table and check if they are all set to 1.

Comment: I've updated my answer to address your clarified scenario

Answer (score -1):

The answer from jbafford will not work in certains conditions.
Let's imagine we have only three possible values: 0,1 and 2. In the case of 0+1+2, the algorithm will say that COUNT = SUM, when in reality, we have a {0,1,2} and not {1,1,1}.
Why do I ask? Because I'm looking for a way in MYSQL to check if it is all ones, and I ruled out COUNT=SUM or in my case, taking the average, as I have this exception in my data.
A way to handle this exception is to add a COUNT DISTINCT. If COUNT DISTINCT=1 **and** COUNT=SUM, then the dataset is only 1s.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow ... please comment on that answer, rather than starting a new answer, if your aim is to point out an error.